# std::unique_ptr reset SIGABRT on virtual destructor

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I spent some time trying to track this down, but I have a small example here that shows the  bug I am seeing. If I ommit the line with reset it works just fine.

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() = 0;
};

Base::~Base(){}

class D1 : public Base {
    public:
        ~D1(){}
};

class D2 : public Base {
    public:
        ~D2(){}
};

struct Foo {
    using MyMap = std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::unique_ptr<Base>>;

    MyMap _test;
};



int main(){
    Foo f;
    /** Works fine **/
    f._test[12] = std::make_unique<D2>();
    f._test[1] = std::make_unique<D1>();

    D2 newD2;
    f._test[12].reset(&newD2);

    /** Execution reaches here **/
    std::cout<<"Foo!"<<std::endl;

    /** Sigabrt on cleanup **/
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles fine on

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.1 20170306 (GCC)
```

Without warnings or errors. But when the program runs and exits it seems to sigbart on cleanup. Valgrind has the following to say

```
==24694== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24694== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24694== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24694== Command: ./test
==24694== 
Foo!
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
==24694== 
==24694== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT): dumping core
==24694==    at 0x427E502: raise (in /usr/lib/libc-2.25.so)
==24694==    by 0x427FCD6: abort (in /usr/lib/libc-2.25.so)
==24694==    by 0x40CC6CE: __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() (vterminate.cc:95)
==24694==    by 0x40CA063: __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) (eh_terminate.cc:47)
==24694==    by 0x40CA0DC: std::terminate() (eh_terminate.cc:57)
==24694==    by 0x40CAED3: __cxa_pure_virtual (pure.cc:50)
==24694==    by 0x8049A29: std::default_delete<Base>::operator()(Base*) const (in /home/aryan/Desktop/Gists/test)
==24694==    by 0x804A946: std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> >::~unique_ptr() (in /home/aryan/Desktop/Gists/test)
==24694==    by 0x804A74C: std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > >::~pair() (in /home/aryan/Desktop/Gists/test)
==24694==    by 0x804A764: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > > >::destroy<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > > >(std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > >*) (in /home/aryan/Desktop/Gists/test)
==24694==    by 0x804A3D6: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > > > >::destroy<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > > >(std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > > >&, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > >*) (in /home/aryan/Desktop/Gists/test)
==24694==    by 0x8049F65: std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > >, false> > >::_M_deallocate_node(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base> > >, false>*) (in /home/aryan/Desktop/Gists/test)
==24694== 
==24694== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24694==     in use at exit: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==24694==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 6 frees, 20,028 bytes allocated
==24694== 
==24694== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24694==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24694==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24694==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24694==    still reachable: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==24694==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24694== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==24694== 
==24694== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24694== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As for the question, am I missing something glaringly obvious or is this a bug? I have no other compiler at hand to test right now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
D2 newD2;
f._test[12].reset(&newD2);
```

You give the `unique_ptr` a pointer to a variable with automatic lifetime. That's a no no.

When the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope it tries to do `delete ptr;` but `ptr` was never allocated with `new` so your `delete` fails and you get a nice SIGABRT. `newD2` will be detroyed by itself because it has automatic lifetime anyway.

This is undefined behaviour with or without the virtual, the virtual just may have been the trigger for the SIGABRT.

Comment: This is one of those d'oh moments. Ty for the swift answer though! For my own sake, did you see this from the valgrind output or did you catch my mistake from the code? I am new to C++ and hard to decipher those errors :)

Comment: @arynaq From your code, it's just practice bud. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use smart_pointers with objects which weren't allocated by **new** operator or created with **std::make_shared** or **std::make_unique**.

In your example **newD2** has its well determined scope. When it leaves its scope (after return) its destructor is automatically called.

In C++ RAII guarantees that the object's destructor is called when it goes out of its scope.

Comment: Smart pointer's don't have to delete their pointees per se. That's just the default. There is a whole zoo of smart pointers and you can pretty much make them do whatever you see fit.